# I am unable deploy a smart contract to hardhat network

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

```js
const {ethers} = require("hardhat")

async function main(){
const SimpleStorageFactory =  await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")  
console.log("Deploying,....")
const simpleStorage= SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
await (await simpleStorage).deployed()
}
```

On this function , I am running into an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContractFactory')
```

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContractFactory') when testing contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628980/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-getcontractfactory-wh)

Comment: import {ethers} from 'hardhat'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.