# Error while compiling smart contract through hardhat

Tags: javascript, solidity, node-modules, hardhat

Error:

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\rehan\Downloads\hardhat-smartcontract-auction\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc\solidity-analyzer.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rehan\Downloads\hardhat-smartcontract-auction\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer\index.js:69:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.4.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.7.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.11.0",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.6.1",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.13",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "solhint": "^3.3.7",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.21"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc": "^0.0.3"
  }
}
```

I've tried creating new hardhat projects and the copied my contract on to that project but still I keep getting the same error over and over again.

Output from `npm install @nomicfoundation/solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc --force`:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.3
npm WARN Found: @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@0.3.0-beta.13
npm WARN node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
npm WARN   dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@"npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@"^2.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.3
npm WARN node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
npm WARN   dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@"^2.0.3" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@2.1.1
npm WARN node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
npm WARN   peer @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@"^2.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.3
npm WARN   node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
npm WARN     dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@"^2.0.3" from the root project

up to date, audited 2010 packages in 43s

162 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

54 vulnerabilities (14 moderate, 37 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I tried downloading the package in the error in order to see if it fixed something. I had to force it because doing it without it was giving me an error

Comment: This looks like a standard Node library problem. How did you install `@nomicfoundation/solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc`?

Comment: I just tried installing it after in saw in the error to see if its fixes something

Comment: What npm command did you use to install it? Try doing `npm install @nomicfoundation/solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc` and add the console output to your question.

Comment: I added the output please take a look at it

Comment: The warnings don't look good. Have you tried destroying your `node_modules` folder and doing a `npm i` (to reinstall everything)?

Comment: I just did it didn't really do anything

Comment: If I was fixing this, I would swap to Node on WSL, Node in a Linux VM, or Node in a Docker container. I don't know that Windows is at fault here, but it would be the first thing I would assume.

Comment: this might have the solutiion for u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628980/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-getcontractfactory-wh